# Populating an array of 365

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops, if-statement

So I am trying to populate an array of size 365, each value in the array is supposed to present a day one day back, the stepy.step.apppend(steps) the first line of the code, fills the array with the step data available from healthkit, however I get nothing back from days with no steps, and I need to fill the days that are not used with 0 in order to set the correct dates for the steps later on.

Edit: So to say, I get steps from healthkit in form of certain dates, however from days with no steps I get nothing, I need to fill those days with 0 value.  I was thinking to do this by first adding the steps and for every day that is 0 or null I add the number 0

```
stepy.step.append(Int(steps))

let numbers = 1...365
let numberCount = numbers.count

var products = [Int]()
products.reserveCapacity(numberCount)
for number in numbers {
    if stepy.step.contains(numbers != 0)
    {
        let product = (number * 0)
        print(product)
        stepy.step.append(product)
    }              
}
```

Comment: if numbers != 0 you multiply number with 0 `number * 0` Multiplying any number by 0 result will be 0. What are you trying to achieve ??

Comment: This is a very muddled question. I'm not actually sure what you are trying to do or what is (or isn't) happening. Can you go back to the fundamentals a bit more in your question to try and help us understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I am trying to extract steps from healthkit from 365 days back in the past, this works perfectly but only returns values from days which are not null. 

I need to put a value of 0 in the days that are not populated by the function, so the array has 365 values

Comment: You mentioned that in the question. But there is nothing in the code you have posted that has anything to with dates or with HealthKit. So I'm not really sure what the code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: It is an array of size 365, the first function step fills the array with steps from various dates. 

However not everyone day 365 back, and those that are not a day, I need to put 0 into.

Comment: Your question lacks a ton of information: what is the source data, and what type is `stepy.step`? `[Int]` or `[Int?]`? What is `numbers != 0` supposed to evaluate to? Currently, you get back true or false, which is probably not contained in the `stepy.step` array, so that line shouldn't compile; maybe you mean to check if the value at the index if non-zero, with `stepy.step[number] != 0`.

Comment: "maybe you mean to check if the value at the index if non-zero, with stepy.step[number] != 0" Ah yes, thank you, that is excatly what I wanted to do.

Comment: Just to make sure you don't fall into a pitfall: **hard-coding a year as 365 days will cause trouble.** There are leap-years, and calendars with weird days-per-year. See http://yourcalendricalfallacyis.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's just that

```
if stepy.step.contains(numbers != 0)
```

should be

```
if stepy.step.contains(number != 0)
```

(Comparing the *number* iteration, not the range.)

But then again, `number != 0` returns a `Bool`, and containment of true/false does not make sense.

---

### An Approach Only Loosely Related to the Question

But for the fun of it, here's a different approach to initializing an array with a certain capacity and inserting values where appropriate.

Note that I added a lot of personal interpretation of what the OP wants to achieve with the `contains` check and all, since the stuff the OP posted did not compute anything:

```
stepy.step.append(Int(steps))
// Indicated `stepy.step` is of type `[Int]`

// If you have to start with an input range, you can use:
//     (1...365).map { _ in 0 }
let stepsOfLastYear: [Int] = Array(repeating: 0, count: 365) 
    .enumerated()   // A different way to obtain an index like in a for loop
    .map { index, value in
        // The only containment check that makes sense: was the
        // source array large enough? -- If not, pass back 0.
        guard stepy.step.indices.contains(index) else { return value }
        return stepy.step[index] }
```

Comment: `(1...365).map { _ in 0 }` can be replaced with `Array(repeating: 0, count: 365)`

Comment: You're right! Will even be more performant (since no iterations are necessary) 

Comment: I just noticed a problem, but the second array stepoflast year is not used, what is it for?

Comment: Since I did not fully understand your question, I extracted the result into a new variable. I'm not 100% sure what your app does since so much info is missing. Maybe it's a replacement for the whole `stepy.step` array if that's where the 365 entries are stored.